# Where can i get c++ standard manual?

Tags: c++, manual

Where can i get c++ standard manual?

Is that free?

***DUPLICATE:*** [Where can I look at the C++ standard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/204841/where-can-i-look-at-the-c-standard)

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, ISO standards are NOT free